# problem firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, persistence

Hi every one I want to set Auth state persistence on firebase to local i'm working on flutter and I don't know how to do that
I found this on firebase web site

```
import { getAuth, setPersistence, signInWithEmailAndPassword, browserSessionPersistence } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence)
  .then(() => {
    // Existing and future Auth states are now persisted in the current
    // session only. Closing the window would clear any existing state even
    // if a user forgets to sign out.
    // ...
    // New sign-in will be persisted with session persistence.
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
  });
```

but not sure how I do that on flutter if any one can help with that

Answer (score 0):

As per the FlutterFire [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage)

> On native platforms such as Android & iOS, this behavior is not configurable and the user's authentication state will be persisted on-device between app restarts. The user can clear the apps cached data via the device settings which will wipe any existing state being stored.

If you're using Flutter for a web app, by default the auth state is stored in local storage. If you want to change this to session based or no persistence you would set that like this:

```dart
// Disable persistence on web platforms
await FirebaseAuth.instance.setPersistence(Persistence.NONE);
```

Comment: i'm making an app for android/ios and I have problem with my Auth it log off each time a navigate between pages so I though may be this will be the solution